# Matplotlib Savefig Function Draws Axes Over Self if Transparent is True

Tags: matplotlib, transparency

I have a program which crunches data and displays the results in a multi-axis figure. I have many different sets of figures, which I'm trying to generate into a report format. To save memory, I'm making a single figure instance and clearing at the end of each loop. Below is an example of the form:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def the_figure():
    #I want a figure that is persistent and accessible
    #So I make the figure an attribute of a function
    the_figure.fig = plt.figure()
    the_figure.axes = dict(
                    t_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(1,0)),
                    t_fit_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(1,1)),
                    o_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(2,0)),
                    o_fit_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(2,1)),
                    table = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(3,0), 
                                    rowspan = 3, colspan = 2)
                    )

#A function which makes figures using the single figure function       
def Disp(i=5):
    try:
        the_figure.fig
    except:
        the_figure()

    pi = 3.141592653589793
    axes = the_figure.axes
    xs = np.linspace(-pi/2,pi/2)

    for n in range(i):
        for name,ax in axes.items():
            ax.plot(xs,np.sin(xs*n))

        the_figure.fig.savefig('test_folder\\bad'+str(n),transparent=True)
        the_figure.fig.savefig('test_folder\\good'+str(n),transparent=False)

        #Clear the axes for reuse, supposedly 
        for name,ax in axes.items():
            ax.cla()
```

When it's finished, the figures save with a transparent=True get an overlay of the curves from their loop AND curves from the previous loop. I have no idea what's going on.

[image: With Transparency]

[image: Without Transparency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(1) # This is as persistent as assigning to whatever function
def init_axes(fig):
   fig.clear()
   return dict(
                   t_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(1,0)),
                   t_fit_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(1,1)),
                   o_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(2,0)),
                   o_fit_ax = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(2,1)),
                   table = plt.subplot2grid((6,2),(3,0), 
                                   rowspan = 3, colspan = 2)
                   )
#A function which makes figures using the single figure       
def Disp(i=5):

   pi = 3.141592653589793
   xs = np.linspace(-pi/2,pi/2)

   for n in range(i):
       axes = init_axes(fig)
       for name,ax in axes.items():
           ax.plot(xs,np.sin(xs*n))

       fig.savefig('bad'+str(n),transparent=True)
       fig.savefig('good'+str(n),transparent=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear your axes you are using `ax.cla()`, but you need to issue `ax.clear()` (or possibly `plt.axes(ax).cla()`).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it. .cla() works on the current axis object, while .clear() works on the axis instance to which it belongs.

Comment: I just changed ax.cla() to ax.clear and I got the same behavior. I also tried changing plt.axes(ax).cla() and I get the same behavior.

Changing the backend, however, can resolve the problem. 'WXAgg' displays the behavior, while using 'Qt4Agg' as the backend fixes the problem. Using Qt4Agg as the backend, it doesn't mater if I clear the axis with .cla(), .clear() or plt.axes(ax).cla().

So I found a 'solution' but I don't understand why it works or what the problem is.

Comment: Based on differences in backend, you might file a bug in matplotlib's issue tracker on github.